# minimal polynomial of powers of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering, given the minimal polynomial of $A$, what can we say about the minimal polynomial of $A^n$?

I know that if we were looking at the roots of the characteristic polynomial ie eigenvalues then the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A^n$ would be $nth$ powers of the eigenvalues so again these are roots of the minimal polynomial also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomials of $A$ and $A^n$ may be different. Consider $A=\lambda I_2$. This has minimal polynomial $m_A(t)=(t-\lambda)$. We have $A^n=\lambda^nI_2$, so that $m_{A^n}(t)=(t-\lambda^n)$. For $\lambda=2$, say, we obtain different polynomials.
Of course, we know the roots of the new minimal polynomial $m_{A^n}(t)$ from the roots of $m_A(t)$, see [Characteristic polynomials of powers and sums of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158972/characteristic-polynomials-of-powers-and-sums-of-matrices).