# What is the characteristic polynomial of power of a matrix

Tags: matrices

If the c.p. of A is $(\lambda-2)^3(\lambda+2)^2(\lambda+3)$, how can I find the c.p. of $A^2$? Would it be $(\lambda-4)^3(\lambda+4)^2(\lambda+9)$?

Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158972/characteristic-polynomials-of-powers-and-sums-of-matrices?rq=1

Comment: Since $A$ has eigenvalues $2, -2,- 3$, it follows that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ must be $4$ and $9$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\begin{align}\chi_{A^2}(t^2)&=\det(A-t^2I)\\&=\det((A-tI)(A+tI))\\&=\det(A-tI)\det(A+tI)\\&=\chi_A(t)\chi_A(-t)\end{align}$$
so that (at least in characteristic $0$)
$$ \chi_{A^2}(\lambda)=\chi_A(\sqrt\lambda)\chi_A(-\sqrt\lambda)$$
If we know the factorization 
$$\chi_A(\lambda)=\prod_k(\lambda-c_k)$$
the we obtain
$$\chi_{A^2}(\lambda)=\prod_k(\sqrt\lambda-c_k)(\sqrt\lambda+c_k)=\prod_k(\lambda-c_k^2), $$
so in your example: $(\lambda-4)^5(\lambda-9)$.

Comment: Note that $$\chi_{A^2}(t^2)=\det(A^2-t^2I).$$

Comment: Can the characteristic polynomial of A^2 be determined using something related to Jordan normal form?